# is this ceiling tile asbestos?

Tags: tile, ceiling, asbestos

Looking to see if anyone can tell if this is asbestos or not
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUZa2.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox81U.jpg

Edit: house was finished in 1984

Comment: When do you think the ceiling tiles were installed?

Comment: Hey there. Your best bet would be to pick up an asbestos test kit from any major home improvement store, or online. Will be more accurate than looking and guessing.

Comment: The test kits from home improvement stores don't do anything.  Just figure out a local lab that will do it.  Google it and there are tons that test for around $30.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Was it abesestos?

Answer (score 2):

No one can tell you if it has asbestos in it except a qualified lab.  Use a spray bottle to wet down a piece of it, carefully scrape off some of the suspect material, put it in a plastic bag and take it to a lab to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the pictures and age of the home I would conclude that you do have asbestos.

A reference site *appears* to have the same tile you've provided (http://www.greatenvironmental.com/accoustic.html)

If you are doing any renovations **STOP** everything, get a qualified professional to come visit the site to do a visual inspection **OR** place a tile in a garbage bag and bring it to them.

A building inspector or qualified contractor can easily confirm this without the need to do lab testing.

**If they confirm you have asbestos, you will need to have them remove it by following your local codes and protocols to deal with this.**